# Electrostatics problem mixed with gravitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

A particle of charge+q is kept a distance d above a neutral infinite sheet
Then in what time the particle reaches to the sheet?

Comment: Hi Bivas and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write anything about the charge of the sheet, I suspect it is neutral. So you can consider only the gravitational force here.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! This is probably best as a comment as its a little too brief for an answer...

Comment: So there is no image charge?

Comment: you mean a negative charge on sheet?